# Blazor Layout = null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

Please, I need a way to master Blazor multi-layered layouts, but for now, I desperately need to know how to null layouts so that I can add everything from `

```
<html>
```

to

```
</html>
```

`

myself on the @page directly.

Why do I want to do this?

in MVC I can make the ViewModel inherit from the _layout ViewModel so that I can dynamically add user images, name, properties... in the navigation and side-nav, even hide some nav options. like in the picture below.

[image: An AdminLTE menu]

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what you want here.  You have Index.html and MainLayout.razor, what is it you can't do with them?  Run-time or Compile-time?

Comment: Run time please @HenkHolterman

Comment: You can inject your ApplicationViewModel and it will be available to any component for example the NavBar or any other custom component.

Comment: ok. Any hope for a null  layout page?

Comment: If you don't want a layout, delete it and don't reference it. If you want to use the built in Router, you will need a layout - but this can be as simple as you like, including a layout that just contains @Body. But this is not a good long term strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to custom your MainLayout?

You can just clear it, open **MainLayout.razor** (where the _Layout lies) and **only add @Body** in it:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@Body
```

From your example, seems you just want to custom your **NavMenu**?

It's the same,open **NavMenu.razor** and just modify the navs.

And for extension, if you want to different types of Layout, you can use NavigationManager to

check the parameter in your url and it will use the related Layout, like:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager _navManager

@if (_navManager.Uri.Contains("CustomLayout1"))
{
    @Body                
}
else
{
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }
```

So if the page is `@page "/CustomLayout1/counter"` Then it will use your null MainLayout in this demo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want multiple layouts.

The base file (_Host.cshtml for blazor server side or index.html for WASM), needs to be as empty as possible to only have  and

For _Host.cshtml, you probably need to do something like:

```
@page "/"
@namespace YOURNAMESPACE.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
     <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</html>
```

For index.html, something like:

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/layouts?view=aspnetcore-5.0